# RecyclerView with SortedList is not sorted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a [SortedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html). The SortedListAdapterCallback is wrapped with a [SortedList.BatchedCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.BatchedCallback.html).

This is the relevant code in the constructor of the adapter:

```
mCallback = new SortedList.BatchedCallback<>(new AdapterPrivateEventsCallback(this));
mList = new SortedList<>(DataEntity.class, mCallback);
```

The data comes from a backend and are loaded in pages. For each item in a page I call `mList.add(item)` and at the end of each page I call `mCallback.dispatchLastEvent()`.

My problem now is that the RecyclerView shows an unordered list.

If I scroll up and down than the items are ordered.

If I use the SortedListAdapterCallback without the SortedList.BatchedCallback the items are also ordered.

Why shows the RecyclerView an unordered list after loading if I use a SortedList.BatchedCallback?

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView only updates any view when `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)` is called. So even though your `mList` gets sorted, it won't reflect on the RecyclerView unless you scroll-out and scroll-in.

If you would like to update the RecyclerView manually you can use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter every time you change the dataset (in your case everytime the callback is called). When this is called the RecyclerView is refreshed and you should get your sorted list.